# R: change specific elements from data frame to colnames and switch rows to columns

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Let's have a list of data tables:

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c("a", "b", "c"),V2=c("d", "e","f"), V3=c("g","h","i"),V4=c("j","k","l"))
df2 <- data.frame(V1=c("m","n"), V2=c("o","p"), V3=c("q","r"))
l <-list(df1, df2)
> l
[[1]]
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  a  d  g  j
2  b  e  h  k
3  c  f  i  l

[[2]]
  V1 V2 V3
1  m  o  q
2  n  p  r
```

I would like to run some code which recognizes some elements:

```
ele <- c("a","b","c","g","h","i")
```

and when finds specific element from the list`ele`

it switches the row to column with specific colname from list `ele`.

Finally, I would like to obtain following data frame

```
df3 <-data.frame(a="d", b="e", c="f",g="j",h="k",i="l")
> df3
  a b c g h i
1 d e f j k l
```

Comment: Does all the elements of a column need to match?

Comment: Try `Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(l, function(x) {i1 <- sapply(x, function(y) all(y %in% ele)); if(any(i1)) do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(x, cumsum(i1)), t))}))`

Comment: If it needs to be named vector `Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(l, function(x) {i1 <- sapply(x, function(y) all(y %in% ele)); if(any(i1)) unlist(unname(lapply(split.default(x, cumsum(i1)), function(z) {z[[2]] <- as.character(z[[2]]); deframe(z)})))}))`

Comment: at least one element should be matched